# Programa con multiples usuarios y contraseñas en c

Tags: c

Tengo un problema, en mi codigo se supone que cuando elija la opción cajero del menu me pida una cuenta entre las 9999 que pueden haber,  al momento de introducir una cuenta correcta usando solamente el if sin el else me lo acepta, pero al momento de introducir el else me marca que esta incorrecta aunque lo haya introducido bien. 
Estoy haciendo uso de estructuras y arreglo de estructuras para guardar los usuarios y contraseñas

¿Es problema del ciclo for? ¿Se puede solucionar? ¿Existe alguna forma de hacer esto sin usar un for?

```
    printf("*MENU PRINCIPAL* \n 1.-Cajero \n 2.-Ejecutivo de cuenta \n 3.- Cliente \n 4.-Salir \n Introduzca una opcion del menu: ");
    scanf("%d",&opcionp);
    switch(opcionp){
    case 1:
    printf("introduce tu cuenta");
    scanf("%s",usuariocajero);

    for(i=0;i<=9999;i++)
    if(strcmp(usuariocajero,cajero[i].usuario)==0)
    {
        printf("ok");

    }
    else
    {
        prinrtf("contraseña incorrecta")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tengo varias dudas.

1) Si almacenas el numero de cuentas, porque no guardarlo en una variable de tipo int?

2) El problema es que al insertar un numero de cuenta, va a empezar a recorrer el array por el 0000 hasta llegar a la cuenta 9999, lo que daria un resultado de 9998 veces incorrecta y 1 vez correcta.
Como por cada lectura del for tenes un printf(), el programa te imprimiria 9998 "Incorrecto" y 1 "ok".
Para evitar esto, deberias poner una variable "bandera" y despues realizar un if sobre esa variable y asi poder imprimir una sola vez en pantalla.

```
bandera = 0;
for(i=0;i<=9999;i++)
{
    if(strcmp(usuariocajero,cajero[i].usuario)==0)
    {
        bandera = 1;
    }
    if(bandera == 1) 
    {
        printf("ok");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("contraseña incorrecta");
    }
}
```

Con respecto a tu pregunta, si, se puede hacer utilizando un while(), pero el concepto seria el mismo, recorda que el for es un while() con un incremento al final de cada ciclo.

Aunque dentro del for el lenguaje permita ejecutar una linea sin necesidad de colocar llaves, es aconsejable hacerlo para poder tener legibilidad del codigo.

Espero que puedas corregir el codigo.

Saludos!

Comment: ¿Por qué obligas al pobre usuario a tragarse 10000 mensajes? La salida debería estar **fuera** del bucle